# Secured Communication between wcf client and php soap server

Tags: php, wcf, security, ssl

Currently I have a non secured communication between a php soap server and a wcf client.
I would like to secure this communication in a way that will include authentication and encryption.

I am trying to find any tutorial or guide that will explain how to configure the php soap server to use ssl.
The php server is running on debian. I created the .pem key using openSSL.

How can I use the .pem key with the wcf client (which only uses .cer).

Comment: Is there *anything* you did research on your own so far about that topic? A *"What do I have to do on the server side for it to work?"* sounds extremely broad to me. Please be more specific.

Comment: A related question: [Convert certificate .pem to .der/.cer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503840/convert-certificate-pem-to-der-cer) covers part of your question. Please specify which part of it didn't work for you or why the question does not apply to your case here.